# Neo4j Query falsely returns null

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using Neo4j v **3.4.1** with Docker.

I run the following **query** via the cypher shell:

```
MATCH (blogA:content {entitySubType:"blog"})-[]->(t:term)<-[]-(blogB:content {entitySubType:"blog"})
WHERE blogA <> blogB 
RETURN ID(blogA), ID(blogB), count(t);
```

The query returns null after some hours. I can not understand or find anything that points me to a solution. When checking the debug log I get the following:

```
2018-09-08 09:53:54.675+0000 ERROR [o.n.b.v.r.ErrorReporter] Client triggered an unexpected error [Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError]: null, reference 549a05ea-3bee-442b-baf5-fd741d37e2db.
2018-09-08 09:53:54.675+0000 ERROR [o.n.b.v.r.ErrorReporter] Client triggered an unexpected error [Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError]: null, reference 549a05ea-3bee-442b-baf5-fd741d37e2db.
java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.resize(HashTable.scala:257)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.scala$collection$mutable$HashTable$$addEntry0(HashTable.scala:157)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.addEntry(HashTable.scala:148)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.addEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.addEntry(HashMap.scala:93)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.getOrElseUpdate(HashMap.scala:79)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.runtime.interpreted.pipes.EagerAggregationPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1.apply(EagerAggregationPipe.scala:120)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.runtime.interpreted.pipes.EagerAggregationPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1.apply(EagerAggregationPipe.scala:118)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.runtime.interpreted.pipes.EagerAggregationPipe.internalCreateResults(EagerAggregationPipe.scala:118)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.runtime.interpreted.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:76)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.runtime.interpreted.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:72)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.v3_4.runtime.executionplan.BaseExecutionResultBuilderFactory$BaseExecutionWorkflowBuilder.createResults(DefaultExecutionResultBuilderFactory.scala:105)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.v3_4.runtime.executionplan.BaseExecutionResultBuilderFactory$BaseExecutionWorkflowBuilder.build(DefaultExecutionResultBuilderFactory.scala:77)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.v3_4.runtime.BuildInterpretedExecutionPlan$$anonfun$getExecutionPlanFunction$1.apply(BuildInterpretedExecutionPlan.scala:97)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.v3_4.runtime.BuildInterpretedExecutionPlan$$anonfun$getExecutionPlanFunction$1.apply(BuildInterpretedExecutionPlan.scala:80)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.v3_4.runtime.BuildInterpretedExecutionPlan$InterpretedExecutionPlan.run(BuildInterpretedExecutionPlan.scala:111)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.LatestRuntimeVariablePlannerCompatibility$ExecutionPlanWrapper$$anonfun$run$1.apply(LatestRuntimeVariablePlannerCompatibility.scala:128)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.LatestRuntimeVariablePlannerCompatibility$ExecutionPlanWrapper$$anonfun$run$1.apply(LatestRuntimeVariablePlannerCompatibility.scala:124)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.exceptionHandler$runSafely$.apply(exceptionHandler.scala:89)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.LatestRuntimeVariablePlannerCompatibility$ExecutionPlanWrapper.run(LatestRuntimeVariablePlannerCompatibility.scala:124)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.PreparedPlanExecution.execute(PreparedPlanExecution.scala:29)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:119)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.javacompat.ExecutionEngine.executeQuery(ExecutionEngine.java:61)
        at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.TransactionStateMachineSPI$1.start(TransactionStateMachineSPI.java:144)
        at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.TransactionStateMachine$State.startExecution(TransactionStateMachine.java:444)
        at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.TransactionStateMachine$State$1.execute(TransactionStateMachine.java:259)
        at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.TransactionStateMachine$State$1.run(TransactionStateMachine.java:240)
        at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.TransactionStateMachine.run(TransactionStateMachine.java:81)
        at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.BoltStateMachine$State$2.run(BoltStateMachine.java:457)
        at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.BoltStateMachine.run(BoltStateMachine.java:225)
        at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.messaging.BoltMessageRouter.lambda$onRun$3(BoltMessageRouter.java:93)
        at org.neo4j.bolt.runtime.DefaultBoltConnection.processNextBatch(DefaultBoltConnection.java:195)
        at org.neo4j.bolt.runtime.DefaultBoltConnection.processNextBatch(DefaultBoltConnection.java:143)
        at org.neo4j.bolt.runtime.ExecutorBoltScheduler.executeBatch(ExecutorBoltScheduler.java:170)
        at org.neo4j.bolt.runtime.ExecutorBoltScheduler.lambda$scheduleBatchOrHandleError$2(ExecutorBoltScheduler.java:153)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

---

We collectively assumed here that the entitySubType is not set for all content nodes. I validatet this assumpttion which is true. Based on this I reformulated my query using exists() predicate function like this:

```
MATCH (blogA:content)-[:TaggedWith]->(t:term)<-[:TaggedWith]-(blogB:content) 
WHERE ID(blogA) <> ID(blogB) AND exists(blogA.entitySubType) AND 
exists(blogB.entitySubType) AND "blog" = blogA.entitySubType AND "blog" = 
blogB.entitySubType RETURN ID(blogA), ID(blogB), count(t);
```

The query retunred null and ended with tex exception again after ~19.1h (3min earlier than last time)

The following query plan is given by the EXPLAIN command: 
[image: Query PLan]

I cannot see where exists(blogA.entitySubType) happens. Moreover, I cannot find the filter "blog" = blogA.entitySubType AND "blog" = blogB.entitySubType.

Is my query wrong or is the query plan visualization not complete?

Comment: Have you attempted with the latest patch release? 3.4.7 is the latest at this point in time.

Comment: No, I haven't. But I am already using the latest official docker image. Can I anyway patch it?

Comment: Are you running the exact same query every time, or is it slightly different each time (e.g., "blog" may be some other value)?

Comment: @cybersam I am running exact the same query everytime and it fails after ~20h. So also the same time.

Comment: @cybersam i reformulated it yesterday and used the exists predicate function. please check the comments in the response of bjornbergq below for the exact query.

Comment: I updated the post. PLease have a look guys and thank you for your help :) @cybersam

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it might be a property that is null, maybe "entitySubType" is not set on all posts?

Is the error consistent or intermittent?
Is the database continously updated, if yes, how?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.The entitySubType should be set on al posts. But for me it sounds also like a missing value or the like. But won't Neo4j just ignore the respective node with missing value? The error occurs everytime after ~20h. So it could be the case that always the same node (with possibly missing value) produces the error. But how can I deal with it? I have no idea how to proceed. The database is not updated. I have a dump of the data and need to evaluate the query in this setting. So my query is the only operation running.

Comment: I think you should make your query to match different nodes based on their ID and not use the value operator <>! Mainly because I think the value operator doesnt handle nodes as a value comparison.

Make it more like:
MATCH (blogA:content {entitySubType:"blog"})-[:TaggedWith|:partOf]->(t:term)<-[:TaggedWith|:partOf]-(blogB:content {entitySubType:"blog"}) WHERE ID(blogA) <> ID(blogB) AND exists(blogA.entitySubType) AND exists(blogB.entitySubType) RETURN ID(blogA), ID(blogB), count(t);

Comment: I formulated the query as follows:               MATCH (blogA:content {entitySubType:"blog"})-[:TaggedWith|:partOf]->(t:term)<-[:TaggedWith|:partOf]-(blogB:content {entitySubType:"blog"})
WHERE blogA <> blogB AND exists(blogA.entitySubType) AND exists(blogB.entitySubType)
RETURN ID(blogA), ID(blogB), count(t);    Still null after ~19h could it be that the curly brackets {entititySubType:"blog"} are evaluated before the exists() function?

Comment: It should be translated to a where clause but try and put it as a where clause instead! But you didnt match by ID in the WHERE clause in the formulated query..

Should be
MATCH (blogA:content {entitySubType:"blog"})-[:TaggedWith|:partOf]->(t:term)<-[:TaggedWith|:partOf]-(blogB:content {entitySubType:"blog"}) WHERE ID(blogA) <> ID(blogB) AND exists(blogA.entitySubType) AND exists(blogB.entitySubType) RETURN ID(blogA), ID(blogB), count(t);

Comment: I updated the post. PLease have a look guys and thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

The property "entitySubType" may not be set in some nodes, that is the reason when the query execution happens the nodes for which "entitySubType" is absent will not be returned. Ensure that all the nodes contain entitySubType property.

Comment: Thx! Can I circumvent this by reformulating the query? For example by using a where clause instead of the curly brackets. I can not understand why the query fails instead of just ignoring the node where the property is missing.

Comment: I reformulated it to the following query and I am currently running it. What do you think? MATCH (blogA:content {entitySubType:"blog"})-[:TaggedWith|:partOf]->(t:term)<-[:TaggedWith|:partOf]-(blogB:content {entitySubType:"blog"})
WHERE blogA <> blogB AND exists(blogA.entitySubType) AND exists(blogB.entitySubType)
RETURN ID(blogA), ID(blogB), count(t);

Comment: you can also use the following query  : MATCH (blogA:content)-[:TaggedWith|:partOf]->(t:term)<-[:TaggedWith|:partOf]-(blogB:content) WHERE blogA <> blogB AND blogA.entitySubType="blog" AND blogB.entitySubType="blog" RETURN ID(blogA), ID(blogB), count(t)

Comment: It is the same as your reformulated query but instead of using both the label matching as well as exists we can simply check for label property after the where clause, it would reduce the complexity of the query.

Comment: I updated the post. PLease have a look guys and thank you for your help :)